# Why the parameter of controller's method is empty Guid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET Core MVC 2

Client side code:

```
static void Get(Uri uri, DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler callback)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += callback;
    // Here uri is http://localhost:61698/Home/Task/aa348338-d367-4635-a5e5-9208c9d0e6a5
    client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
```

Server side (controller's method):

```
[HttpGet]
public string Task(Guid guid)
{
    // Here guid is {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    // instead of aa348338-d367-4635-a5e5-9208c9d0e6a5
}
```

Why here guid is empty & how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not shared your route definition. If you are using the default route definition, you need to explicitly specify the parameter name in the url as it is not named `id`.

This should work.

```
yourSiteBaseUrl/Home/task?guid=aa348338-d367-4635-a5e5-9208c9d0e6a5
```

**Or**

You can change the parameter name to `id` and now you can use the request url in the format `/controllername/actionname/{id}` which is defined as the default route registration.

```
[HttpGet]
public string Task(Guid id)
{
    return id.ToString();
}
```

Now, the url  `yourSiteBaseUrl/Home/task/aa348338-d367-4635-a5e5-9208c9d0e6a5`
 will work

**Or**

If you still want to use the parameter name as `guid`, but want to use the url pattern as `actionName/guidValue`, You can use attribute routing to define a custom route template for this action method.

Define a route template using the `Route` attribute.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Home/task/{guid:Guid}")]
public string Task(Guid guid)
{
    return guid.ToString();
}
```

Now, the url  `yourSiteBaseUrl/Home/task/aa348338-d367-4635-a5e5-9208c9d0e6a5`
 will work